# handle single-dimensional array in Microsoft Interface Definition Language

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-runtime, idl

I am trying to use single-dimensional array in c++ winRT component

Class.idl

```
namespace MyClass
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass Class
    {
        Class();
        String[] aaa(String[] v);
    
    }
}
```

Class.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Class.g.h"

namespace winrt::MyClass::implementation
{
    struct Class : ClassT<Class>
    {
        Class() = default;

        hstring[] aaa(hstring[]  s);
 
    };
}
namespace winrt::MyClass::factory_implementation
{
    struct Class : ClassT<Class, implementation::Class>
    {
    };
}
```

Class.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "Class.h"
#include "Class.g.cpp"

namespace winrt::MyClass::implementation
{

  hstring[] Class::aaa(hstring[] s)
    {
        return null;
    }
 

}
```

then it reports an error in Class.h

[image]

more errors in Class.cpp

[image]

your comment welcome

---

updated question

Class.idl

```
namespace HTMLInterpreter
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass Class
    {
        Class();
        void aaa(Int32[] value);
    
    }
}
```

Class.h

```
#include "Class.g.h"

namespace winrt::HTMLInterpreter::implementation
{
    struct Class : ClassT<Class>
    {
        Class() = default;
     
        void aaa(int[] v);
  
 
    };
}
namespace winrt::HTMLInterpreter::factory_implementation
{
    struct Class : ClassT<Class, implementation::Class>
    {
    };
}
```

Class.cpp

```
void Class::aaa(int[] v)
{
   
}
```

Even I change hstring[] to int[], it will report a similar error

Comment: `hstring[]` is not legal C++. Look in the Generated Files\Sources directory for sample code you can use as a starting point.

Comment: @Raymond Chen, I do not think hstring is the key point, even I change String [] to Int32[], hstring[] to int[](please refer to the updated question at the bottom of the question) , it reported a similar error

Comment: C++/WInRT is still C++.`int[] v` is not how you declare an array of integers in C++, and `int[] function()` is not how you declare a function that returns an array of integers in C++. (As I noted, the files in the `Sources` directory provide the correct declarations.)

Comment: @Raymond Chen  thanks a lot, I got it! it should be com_array<hstring> aaa(hstring const& value), a new question is I can not find the way to add/move item to/from com_array, the description at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/com-array is quite simple

Comment: The com_array is a fixed size container. You don't add items to it; the size is fixed. What you do is construct it at it's desired size. For example you could add the values to a std::vector and then construct the com_array from the vector. The page says "If you're authoring APIs then you'll probably need to construct a winrt::com_array to return a projected array to the caller." There is documentation for each of the ten or so constructors plus suggestions as to how you could use them with certain types of iterators to get specific behavior.

Comment: @Raymond Chen if possible, please change you conmment as answer, I will accept it

Comment: My comment above is really just a sketch. Feel free to write up a complete answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the C++ declaration to use winrt::array_view or winrt::array_view. The syntax you're trying to use isn't valid.